# Save file uploaded by user to wordpress uploads folder

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a page in wordpress and in that i have put this form.

```
<form action=""method="post"enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file"><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" name="name" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Now on clicking submit i want the pic uploaded by user to be saved in folder wp-content/uploads/[posted user name]

Can anyone please help me with the backend processing part in wordpress.I have tried wp_upload_bits,but could nt go with it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the code that you have written as a starting point - rather than expecting someone to provide you with the correct code ... put some effort in and other people may respond with similar effort

Comment: http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-upload-dir/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

user insert_attachment of wordpress to save attachment, then you will also have the functionality to get the images with different styles, get_attachment(id, 'full/medium/thumbnail').

```
$files = $_FILES['upload_attachment'];
foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
  $newupload = insert_attachment($file,null);
  // save the $newupload with you from data, as psot id for the attachment
 }
 function  insert_attachment($file_handler,$post_id,$setthumb='false') {

    // check to make sure its a successful upload
    if ($_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();

      require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
      require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
      require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
      $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );

   if ($setthumb) update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);
     return $attach_id;
 }
```

in html , if you submit the form, images will be uploaded and referances will be saved in wp_post table

```
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <label for="file">Filename:</label>
   <input type="file" name="upload_attachment[]" id="file"><br>
   <label for="file">Filename:</label>
   <input type="file" name="upload_attachment[]" id="file"><br>
   <label for="file">Filename:</label>
   <input type="file" name="upload_attachment[]" id="file"><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I dont want to update the post with the uploaded image.I just want to save the image uploaded by user to the specified folder

Comment: it will upload in the upload folder of wordpress, i

Comment: i want it to upload to folder wp-content/uploads/[posted user name]